# LINQ Grouping by content of an array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

Having some difficulty expanding my linq query.

Suppose I have the following data:

```
Vault      Items
-----      -----
1          100, 102
2          100, 102
3          101
4          101
```

I'd like to flatten this array so I get this:

```
Items      Vaults
-----      ------
100, 102   1, 2
101        3, 4
```

The code that I currently have is this

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;


class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var Vaults = new[]
            {
                new Vault
                    {
                        Id = 1,
                        Contents = new Contents
                            {
                                Items = new[]
                                    {
                                        new Item
                                            {
                                                Id = 100,
                                                Number = "100"
                                            },
                                        new Item
                                            {
                                                Id = 102,
                                                Number = "102"
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    },
                new Vault
                    {
                        Id = 2,
                        Contents = new Contents
                            {
                                Items = new[]
                                    {
                                        new Item
                                            {
                                                Id = 100,
                                                Number = "100"
                                            },
                                        new Item
                                            {
                                                Id = 102,
                                                Number = "102"
                                            }
                                    }

                            }
                    },
                new Vault
                    {
                        Id = 3,
                        Contents = new Contents
                            {
                                Items = new[]
                                    {
                                        new Item
                                            {
                                                Id = 101,
                                                Number = "101"
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    },
                new Vault
                    {
                        Id = 4,
                        Contents = new Contents
                            {
                                Items = new[]
                                    {
                                        new Item
                                            {
                                                Id = 101,
                                                Number = "101"
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            };


        var grouping = Vaults.SelectMany(
            c => c.Contents.Items.Select(s => new { Item = s, Vault = c }))
                                .GroupBy(o => o.Item.Id)
                                .Select(
                                    grouping1 =>
                                    new Tuple<Item, IEnumerable<Vault>>(
                                        grouping1.First().Item, grouping1.Select(o => o.Vault)));

        foreach (var tuple in grouping)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Item(s) {0}: Vault {1}", tuple.Item1.Number,
                              String.Join(", ", tuple.Item2.Select(c => c.Id.ToString()).ToArray()));
        }
    }
}



public class Vault
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public Contents Contents { get; set; }
}

public class Contents
{
    public IEnumerable<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

This query doesn't quite work yet, as it doesn't group on the item list, with a result similar to this:

```
Item       Vaults         //Note: this isn't the output I need
----       ------
100        1, 2
102        1, 2
101        3, 4
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction for fixing this query?
For this example, we may assume that items shared by vaults are always the same. (Meaning Vault 2 **has to** contain the exact same items as Vault 1)

Comment: For what it's worth, I wouldn't call this "flattening" the array - that generally implies a reduction in the dimensionality of the array, which isn't what you're doing here.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Good point, I'll try to come up with another title.

Comment: "Vault 2 has to contain the exact same items as Vault 1" Does the order of items matter?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It doesn't, though I'm sure they'll mostly return in the same order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

First, add `GetHashCode` and `Equals` to `Item`, like this:

```
public class Item {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        if (obj == this) return true;
        var other = obj as Item;
        if (other == null) return false;
        return Id == other.Id;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Next, define a class that can compare sets of items for equality, like this:

```
internal class MultipartKey<T> {
    private readonly HashSet<T> items;
    private readonly int hashCode;
    public MultipartKey(IEnumerable<T> items) {
        this.items = new HashSet<T>(items);
        hashCode = this.items.Where(i => i != null)
           .Aggregate(0, (p, v) => p*31 + v.GetHashCode());
    }
    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return hashCode;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        if (obj == this) return true;
        var other = obj as MultipartKey<T>;
        if (other == null) return false;
        return items.SetEquals(other.items);
    }
}
```

Now your query can be formulated as follows:

```
var grouping = Vaults
    .GroupBy(v => new MultipartKey<Item>(v.Contents.Items))
    .Select(g => new {
        Items = g.First().Contents.Items
    ,   Vaults = g.ToList()
    });
    foreach (var g in grouping) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ---- {1}"
        ,   string.Join(",", g.Items.Select(i=>i.Id))
        ,   string.Join(",", g.Vaults.Select(v => v.Id))
        );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm in my sample code. Actual code doesn't allow for me to add GetHashcode and Equals, but I'm sure I'll find a way around it.

Comment: Just have the `MultiPartKet` accept an `IEqualityComparer<T>` so that you don't need to rely on the built in equality definition of T.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight One more question, though. Could you clarify what exactly is going on in your calculation of the hashcode? How does p*31 + v.GetHashCode guarantee a "unique" hash?

Comment: @Kippie "How does p*31 + v.GetHashCode guarantee a "unique" hash?" It does not "guarantee" it (there's no way to do that in general) but it makes hash codes nicely distributed. Multiplying by a power of a small prime number is a common trick for combining hash codes.